# How can I debug a black screen when testing on a device?

Tags: unity, android, debugging

I have made an Android game with Unity. But, when I opened my game, I see a black screen and a closed game.

It works on a tablet but does not work on mobile phones. I tested it on 2 mobile phones.

On the first phone I installed it on, I see nothing but a black screen and closed game.

On the second one, it installed once and worked, but when I uninstalled it and tried to install it again, I get the black screen and closed game.

What can I do to help me find out what is going on?

Comment: Hey shahin dezfouli! I changed the scope of the question so that it is less broad, and so that it helps you a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer that without any logs. You can use LogCat for that. If you don't have Android Studio installed, go ahead and install it. Once that is done head over to C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools and start the monitor.bat as an administrator. Allow debug mode on your phone and plug it into your PC via USB.
Your device should be shown in the monitor window, click on it, if you don't receive any messages yet. You can see the messages in logcat now in the bottom left corner when you open the tab "LogCat".

Start the unity game and once it crashed, disconnect the device from the USB-port. Then go through the logs and look for a fatal crash messages (red). Copy the whole log and show it here.